# Does node js have a good library for speech-to-text?

Tags: node.js, react-native, speech-to-text

Im working on a project in which the main feature of the project is voice recognition. Th e backend is developed in node, express, and mongo DB, and the frontend is in react-native. I have made a lot of research and tried a lot of examples trying to implement this feature in my application, but I couldn't find any.

I started looking for react-native libraries that might cover this feature, and I did find https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice
I tried to implement it in my project, but I got stuck with an error which is an open issue: https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice/issues/376
I also tried to find other libraries but they weren't good ones. Most of them were developed years ago and never updated.

So I thought to solve this feature in the backend.
I made a lot of research as well, and find a few libraries for speech-to-text, but their documentation wasn't enough, very few tutorials, and not a strong source code to support this feature.

So by far, I am to the conclusion that Node.js and React-native cannot support this feature.
The reason I choose to ask in StackOverflow is to make sure if my conclusion is right(to not waste time trying other libraries), and if it is right, should I try to implement these features by using another programming language(ex: Python), and if my conclusion is wrong, please feel free to share any documentation or solution about this feature.

Comment: Google Cloud has speech-to-text library for nodejs maybe worth to have a look: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs

Comment: If I were to implement such a thing from scratch I would do it in WASM - have you found any WASM speech transcribing libraries?

Answer (score 0):

We do not have such library which will fulful your requirement in nodejs. We have some the API but that are paid one like google speech to text, AI assembly, Deepgram, AWS transcribe, IBM watsonX, Azure transcribe.

I have also tried with open source api like DeepSpeech, Speechbrain, way2letter, kaldi but this  library community is not upto date and this is not running as per our requirement.

We have webSpeechRecognition which is only supported in chrome not in other browser this can be implemented but this is not having much scope.

Only solution is that we can try with paid one if it is OK with you guyz....